# Use a python dictionary for "switch" on datatype

Tags: python, dictionary, switch-statement

I’m trying to write a “switch” dictionary in python.  I want to be able to read in data from a text file and do different things depending on it’s datatype.  So for example if I read in a string I want to compare it to another string.  Or if I read in a float I want to do some operations with it.  It’s a data cleaning operation for a machine learning program.

I could probably do this with an If…Else statement, but since I could conceivably have something for every datatype, I’d rather do it cleaner.

I’m using the following code:

```
varX = 2.0
switchDict = {"bool": "boolean", "int": "integer","float": "floatType",
               "str": "string"}

switchDict[str(type(varX))]()

def boolean():
    print("You have a boolean" )

def integer():
    print("You have an integer")

def floatType():
    print("You have a float")

def string():
    print("You have a string”)
```

It returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Gower71/Switch.py", line 5, in <module>
switchDict[str(type(varX))]()
KeyError: "<class ‘float'>"
```

If I change the switchDict lines to:

```
switchDict = {bool: "boolean", int: "integer", float: "floatType", str: "string"}
switchDict[type(varX)]()
```

It returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Gower71/Switch.py", line 5, in <module>
    switchDict[type(varX)]()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Is there a way to switch on type like this??

Comment: *I’d rather do it cleaner* I'm not sure what you're attempting to do could be called cleaner ;-)

Comment: Oh...  I'm just trying to write a program that builds a dissimilarity matrix for mixed datatypes.  The idea is based on a paper by JC Gower from 1971.  And I'm sure all my python code could be cleaner...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should store the actual function references as values, instead of their names as strings. Example -

```
def boolean():
    print("You have a boolean" )

def integer():
    print("You have an integer")

def floatType():
    print("You have a float")

def string():
    print("You have a string")

switchDict = {bool: boolean, int: integer, float: floatType, str: string}
switchDict[type(varX)]()
```

For this you would need to move the construction of the dictionary to after all the functions are defined.

Also, it would be recommended to not use `string` as the name of a function, it conflicts with [`string`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) which is a standard module. It would be better to use another name, like `string_type` or so.